# How can I detect if a file is going to be installed (or replaced)?

Tags: inno-setup

I have an Inno Setup script in which I need to perform a custom action before a specific file is going to be installed or replaced.

The [documentation](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptinstall) states:

> A `BeforeInstall` or `AfterInstall` function isn't called if Setup already determined the entry it shouldn't be processed.

So I thought I could use `BeforeInstall` to specify what should be done before the file is installed, but it seems that Inno Setup takes the decision of installing the file or not **after** calling the `BeforeInstall` function, so this function is actually called every time.

How can I perform an action just before a file is installed, but not if the file isn't going to be installed (e.g. because its version hasn't changed)?

EDIT:

Here's the relevant pieces of the code:

```
...
[Files]
...
Source: "..\bin\{#BuildConfig}\FooBar.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: uninsrestartdelete; BeforeInstall: PrepareInstallFooBar

...
[Code]
...
procedure PrepareInstallFooBar();
begin
  Log(Format('BeforeInstall: %s', [CurrentFileName]));
  ...
end;

...
```

Here's what the log is showing:

```
...
2014-03-28 10:40:46.778   BeforeInstall: {app}\FooBar.dll
2014-03-28 10:40:46.778   -- File entry --
2014-03-28 10:40:46.778   Dest filename: C:\Users\tom\AppData\Local\MyApp\bin\FooBar.dll
2014-03-28 10:40:46.778   Time stamp of our file: 2014-03-28 10:35:10.000
2014-03-28 10:40:46.778   Dest file exists.
2014-03-28 10:40:46.778   Time stamp of existing file: 2014-03-28 10:35:10.000
2014-03-28 10:40:46.778   Version of our file: 1.0.0.0
2014-03-28 10:40:46.778   Version of existing file: 1.0.0.0
2014-03-28 10:40:46.778   Same version. Skipping.
...
```

Comment: What makes you think that Inno Setup decides whether to install a file after the `BeforeInstall` method is executed ? The [`source code`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/is-5_5_4/Projects/Install.pas#L1622) shows something else. Notice the `ShouldProcessFileEntry` function condition and subsequent call of the `NotifyBeforeInstallFileEntry` method only when the condition passes. Could you show us some specific case ?

Comment: @TLama, I wrote a line in the log in the `BeforeInstall` function, and I can see that it is always executed, just before IS decides to skip the file.

Comment: @TLama, I posted the relevant parts of the code and log file

Comment: But according to the flags you used, the entry will be always installed, thus the `BeforeInstall` method always called.

Comment: @TLama, why would it always be installed? I removed the `ignoreversion` flag in order to avoid installing the file if it's the same version, and IS does skip it...

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed it's a DLL that can possibly have version info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I couldn't make Inno Setup behave the way I wanted, I eventually checked the version myself in a `Check` function:

```
...
[Files]
Source: "..\bin\{#BuildConfig}\FooBar.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: uninsrestartdelete; Check: ShouldInstallFooBar; BeforeInstall: BeforeInstallFooBar;
...

[Code]
function ShouldInstallFooBar() : Boolean;
var
  fooBarTempPath: String;
  installedFooBarPath: String;
  newFooBarVersion: String;
  installedFooBarVersion: String;
begin
  installedFooBarPath := ExpandConstant('{app}\FooBar.dll');
  if FileExists(installedFooBarPath) then begin
    // Get version of currently installed file
    if GetVersionNumbersString(installedFooBarPath, installedFooBarVersion) then begin
      Log('File already exists; version = ' + installedFooBarVersion);
      // Extract new file and get its version
      ExtractTemporaryFile('FooBar.dll');
      fooBarTempPath := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\FooBar.dll');
      if GetVersionNumbersString(fooBarTempPath, newFooBarVersion) then begin
        Log('New version = ' + newFooBarVersion);
        if newFooBarVersion <> installedFooBarVersion then begin
          fooBarShouldBeInstalled := true;
        end else begin
          fooBarShouldBeInstalled := false;
        end;
      end else begin
        // Failed to get version for new file; assume it's different and install it
        fooBarShouldBeInstalled := true;
      end;
    end else begin
      // Failed to get version for existing file; assume it's different and install the new one
      fooBarShouldBeInstalled := true;
    end;
  end else begin
    // File doesn't exist, install it
    fooBarShouldBeInstalled := true;
  end;
  Result := fooBarShouldBeInstalled;
end;

procedure BeforeInstallFooBar();
begin
  // what I need to do before the file is installed...
end;

...
```

Comment: There is no direct way to achieve what you asked for, so a workaround like this is the only way. However, your current code can overwrite a newer version with an older one. You cannot compare version string only for difference. You should determine which one is newer if they differ.

Comment: @TLama, actually that's the behavior I want; if I install an older version of my app, I want this file to be replaced.

Comment: In that case you probably should install it unconditionally.  The user might be running the installer again to try to repair the file, or you might have modified the file and forgotten to increment the version number.

Comment: @Miral, that's what I was doing until now, but this file is actually a shell extension which I need to register when it's installed. My installer runs with no admin privileges, and needs to request elevation to register the shell extension. I want to avoid that when possible, so that the upgrade process is invisible to the user most of the time.

Comment: Why don't you just register it as a per-user shell extension?  It's not reasonable or safe to register it per-machine if you're not installing it per-machine.

Comment: @Miral, ideally I would prefer to do that, but it doesn't work for all the features I need (icon overlays, context menu and autoplay handler)

Comment: All of those should work as per-user extensions.  But regardless, if you have decided that you must register per-machine, then you must install per-machine too.  Then you don't get any of this dodginess in the first place.